# How do I use C functions that have "this" arguments in a C++ program?

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers, variables

I want to copy and paste a C function I found in another program into my C++ program.
One of the function arguments uses the "this" pointer.

```
void cfunction( FILE *outfilefd, const VARTYPEDEFINED this);
```

The C++ compiler errors here on the function prototype:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'this'
```

How do I make this C++ usable?

Thanks.

**EDIT** ( per Betamoo comment )

```
void cfunction( FILE *outfilefd, const VARTYPEDEFINED this);
    {
    UINT8 temp = 0;

    temp = (UINT8)( this & 0x000000FF );

    if ( ( temp > LIMIT ) )
        ......
    else
    {
          ......
    }
}
```

Comment: You're just copy-and-pasting the code?  If so, just rename it.

Comment: it's pretty obvious here, but in general you should quote compiler errors.

Comment: How does the cfunction uses variable this? It may make things different..!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two choices. You can leave the code as C, and just create a C++ header to let you call that C code from C++:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" { 
#endif

    void cfunction(FILE *, const VAR);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Or you can rewrite that function enough to get it to compile as C++ (probably just rename its `this` parameter to something else like `thisvar`).

Answer (score 6):

Rename `this` to something else. C does not have a special `this` variable, it's just a variable like any other.

Comment: `this` isn't really a variable in C++; it's a key word that refers to a pointer value in non-static member functions.

Comment: OK - but it's not a straightforward variable in any language that uses it as a keyword though.. it references other variables.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I'd recommend leaving the original C function unchanged. Put it into a C source file, compile it and `this` as a variable name will be fine. In the header (where the function is declared), you can simply rename the parameter or leave it out:

`void cfunction( FILE *, const VAR);`

(You may need to use `extern "C"` to get the linkage right, see Jerry Coffin's answer).

Answer (score 2):

Is the problem simply that it's trying to name a parameter "this", which is a reserved word in C++?  If so, I think the only solution is to rename the parameter.  You could also put the function into its own .c file and compile it with a C compiler, and then link it into your C++ program (of course the prototype in the C++ program would have to omit the names of the parameters and just put in the types, which is allowed).

Answer (score 2):

this is reserved in C++, it isn't in C, so change this:

```
void cfunction( FILE *outfilefd, const VAR this);
```

to:

```
void cfunction( FILE *outfilefd, const VAR this1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a reserved word in c++.  It refers to the instance of the object in a class method.

You can rename the parameter to anything you'd like, as long as it too isn't a reserved word ;)

FYI, if you're going to be doing a lot of copy and pasting from the "other program", consider using `extern "C" { }`, and linking against the c libraries from the other program.  This is  described in detail in [mixing c and c++](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are just copy/pasting instead of actually trying to call C function from within C++ program. Even otherwise, can you not just rename "this" parameter to something else like "old_this"?

```
void cfunction( FILE *outfilefd, const VAR old_this);
```

Answer (score 1):

A notorious example of this problem (keywords in C++ that weren't keywords in C) happens in X11. Since X11 predates C++ popularity, class wasn't a keyword when X11 was written. But, having to work with C++ compilers, many X11 headers have declarations like the following:

```
typedef struct {
    VisualID visualID B32;
#if defined(__cplusplus) || defined(c_plusplus)
    CARD8 c_class;
#else
    CARD8 class;
#endif
    CARD8 bitsPerRGB;
    CARD16 colormapEntries B16;
    CARD32 redMask B32, greenMask B32, blueMask B32;
    CARD32 pad B32;
} xVisualType;
```